# AutoHotKey Com Object get select list

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, autohotkey, selectedindex

I'm using the following code to just select a drop down menu on a webpage, which I would think would be pretty simple.  Unfortunately, I get an "Unknown Name" error whenever I try to change the selectedIndex of the select list.

This results in an empty message:

```
test := ie.document.getElementByID("mySelect").selectedIndex.Value
MsgBox %test%
```

Here is the the HTML:

```
<SELECT onchange=onchangeSelectOption(); onfocus="hint('Select option');" id=mySelect name=mySelect> 
    <OPTION value=option_1>Option 1</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

I've tried this to change the selectedIndex and manually trigger the onchange event:

```
ie.document.getElementByID("mySelect").selectedIndex := 1
ie.document.getElementByID("mySelect").fireEvent("onChange")
```

I've also tried to get the value in other ways, like:

```
test := ie.document.all.mySelect.selectedIndex
MsgBox %test%
```

as well as:

```
ie.document.all.mySelect.Click()
```

One thing that may be significant.  You can't right-click the select list and view source, but you can do it nearby and find the select list in the DOM.  Also, I believe the options for the select list are loaded dynamically via javascript, so I thought maybe the select wasn't available when I was trying to access it.  I incorporated a long wait time to ensure that everything was loaded, but it still doesn't recognize the name or ID of the select list.

Any ideas?

EDIT:  The HTML is inside a frame.

Comment: Try changing `getElementByID("mySelect").value` to an actual value instead of its selectedIndex. BTW why `ID` and not `Id`? The correct spelling is `getElementById`.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and I still get an empty MsgBox.  The information on this website is very sensitive, so I'm wondering if they've somehow disabled the ability to programmatically see what's in the html?  I would think if I can F12 and view the source, then I ought to be able to copy it using AHK..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may be looking for an answer in the future, I realized the page was using frames, and learned from [this post](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/143981-how-to-click-this-button-using-iedocumentgetelementbyid/) that you have to first target the frame, and then you can manipulate the document within the frame. I was getting an empty MsgBox because I was attempting to find the element with the ID mySelect in a document where it didn't exist.

```
Frame := ComObj(9,ComObjQuery(ie.document.getElementById("_Menu_target").contentWindow,"{332C4427-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}","{332C4427-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}"),1)
msgbox % Frame.document.documentElement.innertext
```